# Show div content after insertion codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

$data['insertion'] = 'true';
          $this->load->view('header'); 
          $this->load->view('clase_view',$data); I 'am trying to show the div content only after  make an insertion and go back to the main page  and then show he div content , i'm usign isset but isnot working

```
</head>
    <body>      
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
          <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href=<?php echo base_url('index.php/clase')?>>Clases</a></li>
                <li><a href="office">Despachos</a></li>
                <li><a href="clase">Otros Servicios</a></li>
                <li><a href="clase">Administracion de usuario</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
         <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                  <h1><strong>Editor de Clases</strong></h1>
                   <?php
                        if(isset($insertion)){
                            echo "<div>Show after insertion</div>";
                        } 
                  ?>
              </div>
               <div class = "row">
                  <p>
                     <a href="clase/create" class="btn btn-success">Nuevo</a>
                  <p>
             </div>

             <div class="row">
                 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                     <tr>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Información</th>
                        <th>Opciones</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php foreach($clases as $clase_item){ 
                        echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>".$clase_item->nombre."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$clase_item->info."</td>";
                            echo "<td align='center'>";
                            echo '<a class="btn btn-success" href="clase/update/'.$clase_item->nombre.'/'.$clase_item->info.'">Editar</a>';
                            echo '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="clase/delete/'.$clase_item->nombre.'">Borrar</a>';
                            echo "</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";   
                    } ?>
             </tbody>
              </table>
          </div>

            <!--Modal para crear nueva clase-->
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Crear nueva clase</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!--Fin modal crear-->
    </body>
</html>
```

after the insertion on `verifynew` method I create the `inserion` variable  but the div content it's not shown

```
function verifyNew(){
       $this->load->library('form_validation');
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Nombre', 'trim|max_length[20]|required|callback_not_repeated');
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('info', 'Informacion', 'max_length[256]');

       if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
         $this->load->view('header'); 
         $this->load->view('clase_create_view'); 
       }
       else{
          if($this->input->post('info')){
             $this->insert2($this->input->post('name'),$this->input->post('info'));
          }
          else{
            $this->insert1($this->input->post('name')); 
          }
          $data['insertion'] = 'true';
          $this->load->view('header'); 
          $this->load->view('clase_view',$data);  
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Tiene que pasar $data a la vista.

You have to pass $data to the view.

```
$data['insertion'] = 'true';
$this->load->view('header'); 
$this->load->view('clase_create_view', $data);
```

Comment: I've edited  my post, but thisway doesnt work too(pasandole $data ala vista sigue sin verse el div)

Comment: Is it the same view? Puedo ver dos vistas: 'clase_create_view' y 'clase_create'.

Comment: No problem! What was it? It'd be good to have here in case anyone else looks at this for an answer.